# How to get active window title in Ubuntu Qt?

Tags: c++, qt, ubuntu

I am using below win API code to capture the active working window title in windows desktop. Is there any alternative in Qt for Ubuntu platform for this implementation ?

```
QString getActiveWndTitle()
{
    char buff[256];
    HWND hwnd = GetForegroundWindow();
    GetWindowText(hwnd, (LPWSTR) buff, 254);
    QString title = QString::fromWCharArray((const wchar_t *)buff);
    return title;
}
```

Comment: Your C cast most likely causes UB in `fromWCharArray`.

Comment: @nwp: It does cause UB (and I cannot see any reason not to use `wchar_t buff[128]`), but OTOH, I would be *stunned* if it didn't work.

Comment: You mean the title of the Qt application window or some other application?

Comment: Do you want the active window *in your application*, or any window?

Comment: The above code is working fine in windows. I am looking for an implementation in Ubuntu

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you want to get the Qt application active window title, you can use

```
QApplication::activeWindow()->windowTitle();
```

If not, you can use QProcess to run an Ubuntu command. This is, xdotool or (if you dont want to install anything) this command:

```
xprop -id $(xprop -root _NET_ACTIVE_WINDOW | cut -d ' ' -f 5) WM_NAME | awk -F '"' '{print $2}'
```

Answer (score 2):

I got it working with below code. We need to install xdotool in ubuntu

```
QProcess process(this);
process.setProgram(“xdotool”);
process.setArguments(QStringList() << “getwindowfocus” << “getwindowname”);
process.start();
while(process.state() != QProcess::NotRunning)
qApp->processEvents();
QString title = process.readAll();
```